# how to find the current owner of the clipboard in python?

Tags: python, pygtk, clipboard

I want to find the current owner who(window/tab/process) owns the clipboard. I am able to find the content which is being copied, but i have to find the window/tab/process from which it is copied. I am using pygtk. Can any one help me in finding this?
I'm a newbie to python.

**Edit:**

I found this  [get_owner()](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkclipboard.html#method-gtkclipboard--get-owner)  and I tried

```
clipboard = gtk.clipboard_get(gtk.gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
owner = gtk.Clipboard.get_owner(clipboard)
print owner
```

And if i'm performing copy operation, it is returning None.
Is there anything wrong or anything else i left

Comment: i don't think there is any clean way to do it other than a brute-force compare with everything!

Comment: i found this [link](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkclipboard.html#method-gtkclipboard--get-owner) but if i'm using, it says None is owner even owner is there. Note: it is taking gtk.Clipboard object as an argument @lalli

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with following:

```
clipboard = gtk.clipboard_get(gtk.gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
```

to

```
clipboard = gtk.clipboard_get(selection=gtk.gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
```

Comment: The get_owner() method returns the owner set by the set_with_owner() method if neither the set_with_data() method nor the clear() method have been subsequently called. This method returns None otherwise.